# How can I place tables after first \autoref when tables are all defined in one place or contained in a separate file called by \input?

Tags: floats, positioning, include

### Background

I have a set of tables that can be automatically generated (specifically, a set of database table descriptions generated by phpmyadmin).

I would like to include each tables in the document after it is mentioned.

I think that I understand how the table placement commands work [htbp], but these are not the issue.

### Question

Is there a simple way to force float placement after a reference?

### Examples

#### This is a MWE of what I have

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\input{dbtables.tex}
% in practice, all tables appear here

\section{tables}

 \subsection{table1}
  \autoref{tab:table1} is for this.
  % I want Table 1 to appear here

 \subsection{table2}
  \autoref{tab:table2} is for that.
  % I want Table 2 to appear here

\end{document}
```

Where the contents of `dbtables.tex` might be

```
\begin{table}[hb]
\caption{test table 1}
\label{tab:table1}
\begin{tabular}{ l c r }
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[hb]
\caption{test table 2}
\label{tab:table2}
\begin{tabular}{ l c r }
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

#### In the end, the result that I want would be similar to:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\input{dbtables.tex}

\section{tables}

 \subsection{table1}
  \autoref{tab:table1} is for this.

\begin{table}[hb]
\caption{test table 1}
\label{tab:table1}
\begin{tabular}{ l c r }
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

 \subsection{table2}
  \autoref{tab:table2} is for that.

\begin{table}[hb]
\caption{test table 2}
\label{tab:table2}
\begin{tabular}{ l c r }
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Except that I want to keep the files separate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's possible to generate the table code in `dbtables.tex` like this

```
\mytable{1}{
\begin{table}[hb]
\caption{test table 1}
\label{tab:table1}
\begin{tabular}{ l c r }
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
}

\mytable{2}{
\begin{table}[hb]
\caption{test table 2}
\label{tab:table2}
\begin{tabular}{ l c r }
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
}
```

then you can define

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mytable}[2]{\@namedef{my@table@\romannumeral#1}{#2}}
\newcounter{mytablecnt}
\newcommand{\placetable}{%
  \stepcounter{mytablecnt}\@nameuse{my@table@\roman{mytablecnt}}}
\makeatother
```

and your input can be

```
\begin{document}
\input{dbtables.tex}
% in practice, all tables appear here

\section{tables}

 \subsection{table1}
  \autoref{tab:table1} is for this.
  \placetable

 \subsection{table2}
  \autoref{tab:table2} is for that.
  \placetable

\end{document}
```

Comment: not the quick setting I was hoping to find but a nice solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`flafter`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/flafter.sty) package:

```
\usepackage{flafter}
```

The package is part of the base LaTeX installation. It takes care that floats will be placed after they have been referenced.

Further useful package regarding this subject are `placeins` and its command `\FloatBarrier`, use it for example to avoid floating over subsection borders, and `afterpage`, for example with `\afterpage{\clearpage}`.

Comment: Does the `flafter` package not force the float placement after its declaration in the source code and not after the first `\ref` to it? The documentation is sparse. A `texdoc flafter` just shows the `source2e` manual.

Comment: `flafter` does not seem to do the trick on my MWE. I will check out `placeins`

Comment: `\FloatBarrier\afterpage{\clearpage}` gives an error, could you give an example of use of the `placeins` with the MWE above?

Comment: @David: Indeed, `flafter` doesn't work like expected. So I would recommend 'storing' the tables code in macros, like egreg did.